# SharePoint 2013 deployment takes too much time

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, solution-deployment

We have a SharePoint 2013 application which has 11 WSP and only one of these WSPs has 12 features. The overall solution works fine, all with good performance.
However, the issue is that when we do the deployment it takes almost 4-5 Hours to complete deployment.

We are using best practice for deployments, like Settings file, Template file, and webconfigupdate files. And we are using PowerShell to do the deployment.
This long deployment time is causing us problem whenever we have more releases/deployments, because our servers are shared with other applications and deployment for our application causes downtime for others.

It would be great if the experts here could suggest what can be done to reduce the deployment time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any info as to why it is taking 4-5 hours?

Comment: Impossible to say based on what you've provided, but my guess is that your solution is poorly architected. Do you really need to push all 11 WSPs every time you update? If so, that's a sign of poor architecture.

Answer (score -1):

Solution Deployment is not a quick job as per my experience.it depends multiple factor

- Number of solution you deploying
- Number of Web Application in the farm
- Number of SharePoint servers in the farm
- Resources available for the deployment

Please check the resource while deployment under process